# bash script that saves each line of the output from the command

Tags: shell-script

I am having trouble writing a bash script that saves each line of the output from the command `#mount | grep ^\/dev/` into a variable.

Below is my bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
mount | grep ^\/dev/ > tempoary
input=$(cat tempoary)
x=0
while IFS= read -r line
do
  x=$((x+1))
  echo "$line" > /tmp/directory/$x
  for file in $(echo "$line"); do
  eval "var$x=$file";
  echo "$file"
  done
done <<< "$input"
```

Output below:

```
[root@localhost tmp]# sh script
/dev/mapper/rhel-root
on
/
type
xfs
(rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/sda1
on
/boot
type
xfs
(rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

I expect to have output format like this:

```
[root@localhost tmp]# sh script
/dev/mapper/rhel-root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

Can you give me some pointers to how I can achieve this?

PS. Double quoting `"$(echo "$line")"` won't help, it would only prompt syntax error below.

```
[root@localhost tmp]# sh script
script: eval: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `('
script: eval: line 14: `var1=/dev/mapper/rhel-root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)'
```

Comment: Clearly `mount | grep ^\/dev/` will give the sort of output you want.  So all this processing is for some other reason.  What is it you're trying to do?  After all, `mount | grep ^\/dev/ | while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done` is a simple loop that displays the same thing.

Comment: I am trying to save the outputs of the "mount | grep ^\/dev/" into variables within shell script, that can be used to further process if it includes certain string within the variable. So for example, the outputs are "/dev/mapper/rhel-root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)" and "/dev/sda1 on /boot type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)" respectively. After saving these 2 lines into variable1 and variable2 in the bash, I would like to further process using if-then-else statement to process if they include string "noexec" within brackets, which is no.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the file directly to `while ... done`:

```
mount | grep ^\/dev/ > tempoary
while IFS= read -r line
do
...
done < temporary
```

or use process substiution to omit the temporary file:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
...
done < <(mount | grep ^\/dev/)
```

or similarly pipe to while

```
mount | grep ^\/dev/ |
while IFS= read -r line
do
...
done
```

Comment: why not `mount | grep ^\/dev/ | while IFS= read -r line` ?

Comment: sure, that works, I just prefer `done < <(cmd)` for readability and habit, but it's simply a matter of choice :-)

Comment: if instructions within `do .. done` span too many lines, I feel loop harder to read as I don't know what is fed to loop, if command or file is before I find it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Adding IFS before for loop and quoting the file variable make things working all fine...
Check this out:

```
#!/bin/bash
mount | grep ^\/dev/ > tempoary
input=$(cat tempoary)
x=0
while IFS= read -r line
do
  x=$((x+1))
  echo "$line" > /tmp/tmp/$x
  IFS=
  for file in $(echo "$line"); do
  eval "var$x='$file'";
  echo "$file"
  done
done <<< "$input"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment

> the outputs are "/dev/mapper/rhel-root on / type xfs
> (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)" and "/dev/sda1 on /boot
> type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)" respectively.
> After saving these 2 lines into variable1 and variable2

Standard variables aren't necessarily the best answer.  Instead an *array* is more likely to be what you want.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

typeset -A mounts

let index=0

m=$(mount | grep "^/dev/")

while read line
do
  mounts[$index]="$line"
  let index=index+1
done <<< "$m"

echo There were $index lines
let a=0
while [ $a -lt $index ]
do
  echo Line $a was ${mounts[$a]}
  let a=a+1
done
```

On my machine, if I run this I get

```
There were 4 lines
Line 0 was /dev/vda3 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
Line 1 was /dev/vda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
Line 2 was /dev/vdb on /news type ext3 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
Line 3 was /dev/vdc1 on /brick type ext3 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```